# hide disabled button and display another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I'm using bootstrap form wizard and my navigation buttons look like this:

```
<ul class="pager wizard">
    <li class="previous">
        <a href="#">Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li class="next">
       <a href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I reach the final step the next button become disabled, I want it to be replaced by submit button instead.

Comment: Can you share your implementation of *when i reach the final step the next button become disabled*? Please create a working snippet using `<>`.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i'm using bootstrap-wizard

Answer (score 0):

Aboud Jouda i assume based on some logic you will know you reached the final step. First add a class to your next a tag. Then execute the below function executeThisOnFinalStep() to change the hyperlink text, remove next class and add final class. Based on this, different onClick function will be executed.

```
<li class="next">
      <a href="#" class="atag">Next</a>
</li>

function executeThisOnFinalStep() {
   $(".pager.wizard.next.atag").html("Submit");
   $(".pager.wizard.next.atag").addClass("final");
   $(".pager.wizard.next.atag").removeClass("next");
}

//Your onClick Functions.
$(".pager.wizard.next.atag").onClick(){
   //write your next logic here
}

$(".pager.wizard.final.atag").onClick(){
   //write your submit logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you try this code:

```
<ul class="pager wizard">
    <li class="previous">
        <a href="#">Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li class="next">
       <a href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

javascript code with jquery:

```
 var finalSteps = 3
    var steps = 3;
    if (steps == finalSteps) {
      $('.next').remove();
      $('.pager.wizard').append('<li><a href="#">submit</a></li>')
    }
```